# Send Email with multiple images in Laravel9

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem that I would like to send Email with multiple images in Laravel9.
I wrote below code.

My goal is send Email with multiple images and
sametime each image file name stores into mysql's 'fileattach' column as photo1, photo2, photo3(one line)

Could someone correct my code please?

**blade file**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">                   
     <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="file_extension|image/*|media_type" multiple>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function saveContact(Request $request) { 
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        if(count($files) > 0) {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                $message->attach($file->getRealPath(), array(
                    'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),custom name      
                    'mime' => $file->getMimeType())
                );
            }
        }        

        $contact = new Contact($request->all());
        $contact->save();

        \Mail::send('admin_email_tpl',  //admin tpl
             array(
                 'sno' => $request->get('sno'),
                 'name' => $request->get('name'),
                 'email' => $request->get('email'),
                 'files' => $request->post('files'),

             ), function($message) use ($request)
               {
                  $message->from('123@123foobar.com');        
                  $message->to('123@123foobar.com');             
                  $message->subject('Thank You');
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, need to put the attachment code into callback method to mail.

```
public function saveContact(Request $request) { 
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        //Get the $files array here    
        $files = [];

        $contact = new Contact($request->all());
        $contact->save();

        \Mail::send('admin_email_tpl',  //admin tpl
            array(
                 'sno' => $request->get('sno'),
                 'name' => $request->get('name'),
                 'email' => $request->get('email'),
                 'files' => $request->post('files'),

            ), function($message) use ($request, $files)
                {
                    $message->from('123@123foobar.com');        
                    $message->to('123@123foobar.com');             
                    $message->subject('Thank You');
                    if(count($files) > 0) {
                        foreach($files as $file) {
                            $message->attach($file->getRealPath(), array(
                                'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),//custom name      
                                'mime' => $file->getMimeType())
                            );
                        }
                    }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Dear @Satyandra Shakya 
Thank you very much for helping me.

I tried your code. However I got 
ErrorException Array to string conversion
at  $contact->save(); line.

Comment: This could be due to a array is being posted from the request in this line $contact = new Contact($request->all()); So you can prepare the record you want to save in contact.

Comment: Dear @Satyandra Shakya 
Thank you again.

I change the line. but I got same error at next 
 $contact->save(); lines. And I tried send email so then 
I remove $contact->save(); line then I got no error. 
but I couldn't get images.